# После миграции Exception

Tags: asp.net

После миграции Exception и проект не запускается
Пробовал убрать строку `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` но не помогло.
Что надо сделать чтобы убрать ошибку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваша "ошибка" не читабельна. Опубликуйте её очень желательно в текстовом виде.

Comment: Ошибка явно намекает что у вас нет сервака sql. Проверьте connectionString или сервис с sql сервером

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удаление файлов миграции